# How to get form specific variable value using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get form specific variable value using Jquery.

I have multiple form in same page and same variable name in each form,  i want to 
read textfield value using form name.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find a set of inputs with a specific name:

```
$(":input[name='" + name + "'")...
```

You need some way to identify the form if the same name is used in different forms. For example:

```
<form id="one">
  <input type="text" name="txt">
</form>
<form id="two">
  <input type="text" name="txt">
</form>
```

would be selected with:

```
$("#one :input[name='txt']")...
```

Generally speaking it's a bad idea to use attribute selectors. A good habit to get into is giving all your form fields unique IDs so you can do this:

```
$("#fieldId")...
```

or if there are multiple, use a class:

```
$(":input.fieldclass")...
```

The `val()` method is used to query or set the value of a form field.

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
$('form[name=foobar] #yourfieldid')
```

you can find more about CSS2 selector [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple javascript

```
var formField = document.forms[form_index].field;
```

or

```
var formField = document.formName.field;
```

or

```
var formField = document.forms["formName"].field;
```

or JQuery

```
var $formField = $('form[name="formName"] > input[name="fieldName"]');
```

**Updated** my JQuery statement.
It only takes every field within the form with that name `fieldName`

Answer (score 0):

I know many years passed since the question. However, here is a simple selector:

`var $field = $('#formId #fieldId');
var value = $field.val();`